# Separate long and complex names in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-manipulation

Say I have the following list of full scientific names of plant species inside my dataset:

```
FullSpeciesNames <- c("Aronia melanocarpa (Michx.) Elliott", "Cotoneaster divaricatus Rehder & E. H. Wilson","Rosa canina L.","Ranunculus montanus Willd.")
```

I want to obtain a list of simplified names, i.e just the first two elements of a given name, namely:

```
SimpleSpeciesNames<- c("Aronia melanocarpa", "Cotoneaster divaricatus", "Rosa canina", "Ranunculus montanus")
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: It's not exactly what you ask, but you can use function `gnr_resolve()` from the `taxize` library: `gnr_resolve(FullSpeciesNames,best_match_only = T,canonical=T)`. This will output the Genus species name only, but also allow to deal with species name synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match a word (`\\w+`) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) followed by another word and space, capture as a group, and the rest of the characters (`.*`).  In the replacement, use the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
trimws(sub("^((\\w+\\s+){2}).*", "\\1", FullSpeciesNames))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that is more complicated in function use, but does not require regular expressions is

```
substring(FullSpeciesNames,
          1, sapply(gregexpr(" ", FullSpeciesNames, fixed=TRUE), "[[", 2) - 1)
[1] "Aronia melanocarpa" "Cotoneaster divaricatus" "Rosa canina" "Ranunculus montanus"
```

`gregexpr` can be used to find the positions of certain characters in a string (it can also look for patterns with regular expressions). Here we are looking for spaces. It returns a list of the positions for each string in the character vector. `sapply` is used to extract the position of the second space. The vector of these positions (minus one) is fed to `substring`, which runs through the initial vector and takes the substrings starting from the first character to the indicated position.